# How can I strip html with BeautifulSoup, keeping newlines like textContent?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, newline, whitespace

This is what I've got:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> BeautifulSoup("<p>Hello</p>\n\n<p>World</p>").get_text()
u'Hello\nWorld'
```

Whitespace is mostly preserved but, as in the example above, newlines aren't. I'd like to strip HTML without any whitespace normalisation, matching javascript's `textContent`. Can `BeautifulSoup` do this?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than the default parser, `html.parser`, installing `html5lib` did the trick:

```
pip install html5lib
...
>>> BeautifulSoup("<p>Hello</p>\n\n<p>World</p>", "html.parser").get_text()
u'Hello\nWorld'
>>> BeautifulSoup("<p>Hello</p>\n\n<p>World</p>", "html5lib").get_text()
u'Hello\n\nWorld'
```

See [installing-a-parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).